# netty inbound outbound to pipeline fails

Tags: netty

As you will see, I am new to netty.  I wonder why nothing happens after adding this class to the pipeline.  I am using version 4.0.25.Final.  Alle the inbound handlers I use are added fine and works when I test.

```
public class SipChannelInboundOutboundHandlerAdapter implements
    ChannelOutboundHandler, ChannelInboundHandler {

private Logger mainLogger = ServLogger.getMainLogger();
private Logger consoleLogger = ServLogger.getConsoleLogger();

@Override
public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause)
        throws Exception {
    cause.printStackTrace();

}

@Override
public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

AbstractResponse response;

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
        throws Exception {
    consoleLogger.info("channelRead");
    if (msg instanceof Unauthorized)
        response = (Unauthorized) msg;

}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {


}

@Override
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void channelWritabilityChanged(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void bind(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, SocketAddress localAddress,
        ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void connect(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, SocketAddress remoteAddress,
        SocketAddress localAddress, ChannelPromise promise)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void disconnect(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelPromise promise)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void close(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelPromise promise)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void deregister(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelPromise promise)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void read(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg,
        ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
    ctx.write(response);
    ctx.flush();
    if(!promise.await(2000))
        consoleLogger.info("not written to Outbound handler");
    else
        consoleLogger.info("written to Outbound handler");


}

@Override
public void flush(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Note: The loggers work fine in the inbound handlers

Is it due to not adding required code to one of the overriden methods?

Answer to comment:
The .addLast method containing an instance of this class never returns.  The Junit test bringing up my server(setupBeforeClass method) just stalls.

```
                            ChannelPipeline cp = ch.pipeline();
                        cp.addFirst("logger", new LoggingHandler());
                        cp.addLast("parser", new SipSimpleChannelInboundHandlerAdapter());
                        cp.addLast("javaee", new SipChannelInboundHandlerAdapter());
                        consoleLogger.info("adding inboundoutbound");
                        cp.addLast("test_return_message", new SipChannelInboundOutboundHandlerAdapter());
```

The last thing that happens on the console is the line "adding inboundoutbound", then I have to stop the test using the red button(eclipse).

Commenting out the last addLast method makes the test go as expected. ReadComplete methods in all inbound handlers are called(fired in prevous handler where necessary), but when trying to add the last handler, which is not extending an adapter but implementing both ChannelInboundHandler and ChannelOutbounHandler, I experience this.

Comment: can you mention what exactly is going wrong? I am a little unclear. You added them to the pipeline and the handlers don't get called?

Comment: No, the bootstrapping halts when I add the combined InboundOutbound handler.  I also tried with a class extending ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter and implementing ChannelOutboundHandler interface.  Same thing.

Comment: Seems the problem is when i implement ChannelOutboundHandler.

Comment: Did you forward the event to the next handler in your handler implementation? One way to do that is to call `ctx.fire*()` or `ctx.<operation>()`.

Comment: Yes, I am calling ctx.fireChannelRead in the method with the same name in the prevoius handler.  Anyway, shouldn't the pipeline get loaded irrespective of content in the handlers? That's what happens, the code just stops running, or loops and no exception is thrown.

Comment: So what I am saying is, the test I am running is supposed to bring up netty as a server with the pipeline above.  It is then supposed to use netty again to send a client request to the server, but the test halts when the inboundoutbound handler is added.  Removing the handler makes the test run as far as it can, i.e. the request is received by the server.

Comment: Tried adding the handler from a method in one of the other handlers.  It works.  So I have a workaround.